# a phrase to describe a greedy scoundrel, or to name that behaviour

Tags: phrase-requests

Imagine the following conversation:

```
B: What's the price?
A: It's fifteen each.
B: Okay, I'll buy it.
A: Too late, now it's twenty each.
B: Why? Because I can afford fifteen?
A: Exactly.
```

How would you describe A or A's method? A is a scoundrel, his method greedy. Is there a better word for it, or a more precise one?

Such a conversation is not new at all. Perhaps some famous writer made use of it in one of his or her novels, and I can take the name of the character who is a seller.

I am debating a slightly more complicated bargain strategy than the previous example:

```
B: What's the price?
A: It's fifteen each.
B: Okay, I'll buy a dozen.
A: You can only buy one at this price, the next will be twenty.
B: Why? Because I can afford fifteen?
A: Exactly.
   And I'll keep raising the price to test your bottom line.
```

As you can imagine, this strategy, or its variants, are employed by some e-commerce websites. It cannot go without a name, but I am not yet in the industry to know its name, and I didn't find it when I googled it. Since I am not specifically addressing e-commerce, I may as well improvise one for the convenience of debate.

**Edit**: in the end I used the term "Lowball technique" as suggested by the chosen answer.

Comment: As I detect from your name that you are probably Chinese, please tell us what the Chinese would call such a person. You see, I've been married to a Chinese for a very long time and have been visiting the East for over 40 years. The word 'greedy scoundrel' leaped off the page at me as a direct translation of something I may have heard before!

Comment: Yes I am Chinese. I think you are looking for 贪得无厌, direct translate to "greedy and insatiable". Directly translating 'greedy scoundrel' to Chinese you would get 贪得无赖, a improvise (i.e. non-existant) phrase that is only one character away from that common phrase.

Comment: I felt sure 'greedy scoundrel' was a direct translation from Chinese the moment I saw it. Though my wife has spoken Cantonese and Hakka from childhood, she did all her education in Malaysia when the taught medium was English. Thus sadly she doesn't read Chinese characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By pure luck I came across this term which describes a similar sales technique:
**[Lowball Technique](http://psychcentral.com/encyclopedia/2009/lowball-technique/)**

> An unscrupulous sales technique where customers are initially quoted a lower price, then informed that there has been a mistake and the actual price is higher. Customers who initially agree to pay the lower price are much more likely to continue with the sale at the higher price.

[Low-ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-ball)

> The low-ball is a persuasion and selling technique in which an item or service is offered at a lower price than is actually intended to be charged, after which the price is raised to increase profits.
>   An explanation for the effect is provided by cognitive dissonance theory. If a person is already enjoying the prospect of an excellent deal and the future benefits of the item or idea, then backing out would create cognitive dissonance, which is prevented by playing down the negative effect of the "extra" costs.

Also, perhaps:
[unscrupulous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unscrupulous) *adj.
Devoid of scruples; oblivious to or contemptuous of what is right or honorable.*

An unscrupulous businessman (for example) is one who will think first and foremost of his own interests and will stop at nothing in order to achieve his aims. In doing so he may employ several tactics which may or may not be legal, but which many would claim are dishonest.

Thus the character's behaviour could be described as being *unscrupulous, manipulative* and *devious*.

Some examples from [allbusiness.com](http://www.allbusiness.com/banking-finance/banking-finance-overview/15079037-1.html):

> **Measures announced to combat unscrupulous landlords**
>   "Local authorities in England are to receive a share of £4 million to
>   tackle rogue landlords, as part of a package of measures announced by
>   the Government to increase the quality of rental properties. The
>   funding, which has been allocated to 23 councils, will help them
>   tackle *unscrupulous landlords renting out dangerous, dirty or
>   overcrowded properties*."
>
> **5 Tips to Avoid Unscrupulous Factoring Companies**
>   "This week I heard a story from an Austin Texas company about the common unscrupulous practice of filing a UCC-1 financing statement against it by a Central Texas based factoring company before they had agreed to do business together."

Comment: Would you be so kind to seperate your "Lowball Technique" to an answer on its own, so that I can confirm that one? That is a precious description of the scenario. "unscruplous" is a suitable word, but "Lowball" is so precious that it has to be the winner:) Otherwise I'll come back to choose your existing answer in 7 days of inaction.

Comment: @ZhangWeiwu could you not edit in your answer that you accepted "low-ball"? I am not sure what the procedure is in cases like these, I've never been asked to separate my answer before. If I had not searched for references to back up my suggestion, unscrupulous, I would not not have chanced upon "low-ball".

Comment: Ahh, seven days of inaction...  it's quite a bit!

Comment: Oh, with a modern technology, "smartphone", you can set the event to any day away without worrying about forgetting. But it seems a confirmation in 2 days gives more reward points to you, thus I should come back in 2 days. I am new to the game and am learning the rules. You suggest "could you not edit in your answer"; I guess you meant "could you not edit in your question" and did that.

Comment: Thank you @Kriss for brilliant editing work, something as simple as switching the order (plus resizing) has made a huge difference. Thank you again. Yes, Zhang Weiwu luckily you understood my suggestion.

Comment: The term 'lowball' is American and is rarely used in Britain, probably because it has something to do with baseball or some game where a low delivery is considered unfair. In cricket it is high balls that you need to watch out for, the ones where the ball comes at you at about 100mph and tickle your ears! We consider a 'low blow' (boxing) to be unfair, but 'lowballing' carries no resonance among the cricket playing nations of the world. They are the ones like your auntie bowls.

Answer (score 3):

**[Gazumping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gazumping)**

> Gazumping occurs when a seller (especially of property) accepts an oral offer of the asking price from one potential buyer, but then accepts a higher offer from someone else. It can also refer to the seller raising the asking price at the last minute, after previously orally agreeing to a lower one. In either case, the original buyer is left in the lurch, and either has to offer a higher price or lose the purchase.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gazumping) The term gazumping is most commonly used in the UK and Australia, although similar practices can be found in some other jurisdictions.

This is a word that became popular in Britain in the 1970s, and has been used a lot since, especially when house prices are rising sharply.

It means something very particular, and is less common in the United States where land conveyancing laws are different.

Person A puts their house on the market for sale at a particular price. Person B comes along and offers (verbally) the asking price. Now person B does not actually own the house until contracts are signed, and searches are made by lawyers for clear title etc. These legal processes can take several weeks. In the United States, and in Scotland, the time gap between offer and completion is much shorter, (which has both advantages and disadvantages).

If, while the legal processes are in hand Person A finds they could have sold the house for more, he may telephone Person B and tell him or her that if they still want the house that they will have to pay a further £10,000, or something. There is nothing that Person B can do about it if they still want to buy. They are said to have been *gazumped*!

Comment: +1 *...the seller raising the asking price at the last minute, after previously orally agreeing to a lower one.* That sounds quite like what the OP means.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior could be characterized as **[mercenary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mercenary?q=mercenary)**

> (of a person or their behavior) primarily concerned with making money at the expense of ethics:
>
> *she’s nothing but a mercenary little gold digger*

The term **[jack up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/jack+up)** may also be used

> to raise the price of something.
>
> *The store keeps jacking prices up.*
>
> *The grocery store jacked up the prices again last night*

The scenarios described are fairly aggressive forms of *jacking up* prices.

Comment: -1 Etymologically, the word has its roots in working for others in return for payment. Any "unethical" part of the behavior is only 'incidental to the discharge of duties', not a character trait. *Hireling*. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mercenary

Answer (score 0):

**[shenanigans](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=shenanigans)**? -- the behavior

> reckless or malicious behavior that causes discomfort or annoyance in others
>   the use of tricks to deceive someone (usually to extract money from them)

Moshe Adler *[Economics for the Rest of Us](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=CxVa0zM3y9kC&pg=PA187&dq=%22shenanigans%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=scfkUvzGAsyUrgfF1IGQCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22shenanigans%22&f=false)*:

> "Savvy businesspeople that they are, the directors know that, while it is the shareholders who pay them, in most cases  the only candidates for directorships are those nominated not by shareholders but by the CEOs themselves.
>   "But … nobody gets cheated. People who buy the company's shares are well aware of the possibility of these **shenanigans**." [emphasis added]

Comment: 'Shenanigans' is much more general than what is desired by the OP.

Comment: @Mitch Yes. The "?" was always there with the suggested word. :)

Answer (score 0):

Admiring all the answers, 
I can only add that if you are still determined to go on with the order, a good thing to consider would be killing off all your cookies, as the same kind of politics is employed by the tickets-selling websites to up the ticket price every time you return to finalize the purchase. Mercenary I call it!